# Navigate through all the members of Research Gate Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am a rookie in python selenium. I have to navigate through all the members from the members page of an institution in Research Gate, which means I have to click the first member to go to their profile page and go back to the members page to click the next member.I tried for loop, but every time it is clicking only on the first member. Could anyone please guide me. Here is what I have tried.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib

driver = webdriver.Firefox("/usr/local/bin/")

university="Lawrence_Technological_University"

members= driver.get('https://www.researchgate.net/institution/' + university +'/members')

membersList = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("ul")

list = membersList.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")

for member in list:
     driver.find_element_by_class_name('display-name').click()
     print(driver.current_url)
     driver.back()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not even doing anything with the list members in your for loop. The state of the page changes after navigating to a different page & coming back, so you need to find the element again. One approach to handle this is given below:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
     membersList = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("ul")
     element = membersList.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")[i]
     element.click()
     driver.back()
```