# How to prevent my script from breaking after the first loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python using selenium to get some specific information from a webpage. As the webpage is a confidential one, I can't reveal the site address. Anyways, I was expecting that my existing scraper will click each link out of 20 links from a webpage and reaching the desired page it will collect the info and get back to earlier page and repeat the same until all the 20 links are exhausted. However, the scraper clicks on a link, go to the desired page parse the info but instead of getting back to main page to repeat the operation, it breaks. It seems there is something wrong with my looping process. Here is some lines from my script which may give you any idea to provide me with a workaround.

```
for link in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".section-result"))):  ##Supposed to loop through all the links
    link.click()   ##clicking each link

    name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".section-info-text")))[2] ##this is where the document i want to parse from. The browser gets here when a click is executed 
    print(name.text) #after parsing the docs the code breaks instead of getting back to main page
```

Please, care to scroll rightmost to see the minimum description attached to each line. Thanks.

This is the error I'm having:

```
line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is essentially this:

1. You get all the links as WebElements to iterate over
2. You start your loop
3. You click the first link which brings you to a new page, causing that list of WebElements to go stale
4. You try to continue using the stale WebElements, even though they are no longer connected to anything.

What you can do instead:

pseudo code

```
linkCount = getCountOfLinks();

for x in range(0, linkCount-1):
    #Get all the links again fresh, and pick the next one each iteration
    link = getAllTheLinks[x]; 

    link.click();

    #the rest of your stuff
    name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".section-info-text")))[2]  
print(name.text)
```

Answer (score -1):

If the code isn't going back to the main page, you may need to execute a command that will return to the previous (main) page, such as a back button of some sort. I am not a selenium expert, but I have used Protractor (javascript wrapper for selenium) and have seen issues like that.

Comment: Thanks jGraves for your answer. Before posting my question I tried with `driver.back()` this command in the appropriate position but no luck. Still the same.

Comment: @Topto: You need to find the elements again when you are back on the page after `driver.back()` is executed. You can look at my last answer for reference at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46707691/975114

Comment: Thanks Amit. I suppose this clue might do the trick. I'll let you know.